# Не выполняется вход при наличии скрипта в profile.d

Tags: linux, debian

День добрый. Имеется в `/etc/profile.d/` скрипт на `bash`, который по задумке выводит различную инфу при коннекте по SSH.

Однако после перезагрузки машины, логин через графическую оболочку стал просто невозможен (окружение Gnome): выбираю юзера, ввожу пароль, попадаю опять на окно с выбором юзера. При этом в терминале скрипт запускается без проблем, при коннекте по SSH тоже.

После удаления скрипта оттуда, вход через графическую оболочку заработал.

Как можно это исправить?

UPD. скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash

# Font furniture
b=$(tput bold);
n=$(tput sgr0);

# Functions

func_PrintResourceUsage() {

  if [ -z "$3" ]; then
    echo -e "\t${n}$1\t\t${b}$2${n}";
  else
    echo -e "\t${n}$1\t\t${b}$2${n}\tof \t${b}$3";
  fi;

}

echo -e;

# CPU info
loadavg=$(cat /proc/loadavg);

echo -e "${LinesPrefix}${b}CPU usage:";
func_PrintResourceUsage " 1 min" $(echo $loadavg | awk '{ print $1 }') "";
func_PrintResourceUsage " 5 min" $(echo $loadavg | awk '{ print $2 }') "";
func_PrintResourceUsage "10 min" $(echo $loadavg | awk '{ print $3 }') "";

echo -e;

# RAM info
RAMTotal=$(free -h | awk 'FNR == 2 { print $2 }');
RAMUsed=$(free -h | awk 'FNR == 2 { print $3 }');
SWAPTotal=$(free -h | awk 'FNR == 3 { print $2 }');
SWAPUsed=$(free -h | awk 'FNR == 3 { print $3 }');
echo -e "${LinesPrefix}${b}Memory usage:"
func_PrintResourceUsage "RAM" ${RAMUsed} ${RAMTotal};
func_PrintResourceUsage "SWAP" ${SWAPUsed} ${SWAPTotal};

echo -e;

# Disc space info
MountArr[0]="/";

echo -e "${LinesPrefix}${b}Disc usage:";

for Mount in "${MountArr[@]}"; do

  MountPointInfo=$(/bin/df -Th $Mount 2>/dev/null | tail -n 1);
  MountPointFreeSpace=( \
       $(echo $MountPointInfo | awk '{ print $4 }') \
       $(echo $MountPointInfo | awk '{ print $3 }') \
  );

  func_PrintResourceUsage $Mount ${MountPointFreeSpace[0]} ${MountPointFreeSpace[1]};

done
echo -e;
#users

UsersOnlineCount=$(users | wc -w);

echo -ne "${LinesPrefix}${b}Users logged in:"
echo -e " ${b}${UsersOnlineCount}";
echo -e;

# uptime

SystemUptime=$(uptime | sed 's/.*up \([^,]*\), .*/\1/');
echo -ne "${LinesPrefix}${b}System uptime:"
echo -e "\t${b}${SystemUptime}";
echo -e;
```

Comment: Покажи скрипт. И некоторые скрипты лучше ложить в bash-rc.d

Comment: обновил вопрос. Меня смущает то, что в терминале он пашет без проблем, но при логине через графическую оболочку что-то не срастается

Comment: ещё наткнулся где-то, что оконный менеджер может использовать `/bin/sh`. Может ли быть проблема в этом?

Comment: Класть (@eri, обратите внимание) скрипты лучше к пользователю в домашний каталог, а уж если что-то хочется сделать глобальным, то стоит избавиться от bash-зависимости (только чистый shell) и подумать, в каком месте он должен лежать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрипты в profile.d запускаются по очереди, переменная PATH может быть ещё не установленна и скрипт выдаст exit 1 на одной из команд, что прерывает выполнения скриптов далее. Граффическая оболочка может не запуститься без прогрузки своих переменных окружения, тот же самый PATH.

Рекомендую положить этот скрипт в bash.rc, чтоб он выполнялся только при входе в баш